# Accessing MySQL using Java on Windows?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm learning java programming in windows operating system. And I'm wondering how can I possible to access my MySql database using Java language? Do I need to install additional drivers?

Comment: Honestly, SO is not a mechanical turk replacement for google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the mySQL JDBC driver to your project libraries.

http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Here is an official link provided from the mySQL tutorials section of examples on how to make a connection:

http://www.developer.com/java/data/jdbc-and-mysql-discussion-and-sample-code-for-jdbc-programs.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/):

> MySQL Connector/J is the official JDBC driver for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, driver is named [Connector/J](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). It's JDBC level 4 driver.